# Auth returning 401

Tags: python, cookies, bearer-token

I'm trying to retrieve data from my code below.
The token is correct, and when I'm trying by ThunderClient, I receive data.
But when running the code below, I receive 401 - Unauthorized, Authentication Required.

As I'm still learning Python, I cannot see why it is not working.

Could someone give me an idea on how to solve it?
Thanks a lot!

```
import requests
import json 
import urllib.request
import os.path
import os

bearer_token="908yt"

headersAuth = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}



response = requests.get("https://mywebsiteexaple.com/api/", headers=headersAuth)



payload=response.json()
print(payload)
```

Comment: URL is not valid

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The code is 401! I have tried by ThunderClient on vscode and I receive data, I got 202. But when running my script is not working.

Comment: The url is just an example.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with your code, you are passing Bearer token correctly. May be it is easier to troubleshoot if can share details about request you are accessing from ThunderClient.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. The Thunder client was saving a cookie from a previous request that made it work.
It's a shame that Thunder client doesn't show the cookies being sent.